# how to save multiple images on single click into database and folder in mvc 5 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

i got stuck with this, i have to save multiple images into database and folder on single post

my view is

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" })
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" })
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Driverimage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" })
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Driverimage, new { type = "file" })
        @Html.ValidationMessage("Custom Error")
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DriverLiscenseimage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" })
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.DriverLiscenseimage, new { type = "file" })
        @Html.ValidationMessage("Custom Error")
    </div>
</div>
```

my controller is

```
      [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterDriver(DriverRegistration newRecord,HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        if (file != null)
        {
            string ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/images/" + ImageName);

            // save image in folder
            file.SaveAs(physicalPath);

            //save new record in database

            newRecord.FirstName = newRecord.FirstName;

            newRecord.DriverFilename = ImageName;
            objentity.DriverRegistrations.Add(newRecord);
            objentity.SaveChanges();

        }
        return View();
    }
```

please help me with this ....
Iam saving it it in image folder but only single image is saved

Comment: Do you have any table to store image path ?

Comment: yes, images folder in the soltion explorer

Comment: but where you will store the path of those images ?